# Numerical calculation of skyrmion number

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, nanoscience, ferromagnetism

I'm having trouble finding a numerical method to calculate the skyrmion number for a certain system. I want to calculate 
$$ n = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int \textbf{M} \cdot \left( \frac{\partial \textbf{M}}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial \textbf{M}}{\partial y} \right) dxdy$$

for a simulation I performed. The simulations results are in an archive with the following format

($x_1$,$y_1$,$M_{x1}$,$M_{y1}$,$M_{z1}$)

($x_2$,$y_2$,$M_{x2}$,$M_{y2}$,$M_{z2}$)

.

.

($x_N$,$y_N$,$M_{xN}$,$M_{yN}$,$M_{zN}$).

I had an idea of using cubic splines to interpolate the points and then integrate with any method. That way, with the splines i should have the value of the partial derivatives. The problem is I can't find lots of information about these splines for multivariable functions, just for one variable. I would like to know if there's another -and more efficient- method or should I keep going with the idea I have, in which case I would really appreciate some sources or tips to achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: Are the points on a grid? Have you tried just approximating the partial derivatives using finite differences?

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, the points are on a grid. The simulations I ran are from OOMMF and then I manipulate a little bit the data so the archives would look like what I wrote. I don't know if finite diffrences would work well because the grid I have may not be sufficiently small

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the skyrmion number discretising the integrals using finite differences, and then using the midpoint rule for the numerical integration. It's a rough approximation but it gives reasonable results, specially if your FD mesh has a decent resolution.

I wrote a tool to compute the sk number from OOMMF files a while ago, you can give it a try or check the documentation of the function

https://github.com/davidcortesortuno/oommfpy